# Is there is anyway to make SOME desktop icons smaller on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

recently I found my self needing some shortcuts to some files on my desktop, but it doesn't fit in the desktop with the current size of icons which I like and I don't want to change, so is there is any way to make some icons smaller that I just find them when I need them while remaining the others big so they stand out.
Note: I'm using windows 10 version 1903 OS build 18362.295
Thanks in advance for answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change icon size or positioning in Windows 10 for only certain icons. Icon size and layout options in Windows are all universal.

There may be third party theming engines which may offer such flexibility, but you will not find these features within a default Windows install.

Comment: I looked around and found that there are some apps that allow you to customize the desktop with themes, a theme that simulates exactly how the actual desktop look and work(I really don't know if that's possible) while giving us this extra feature would come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I agree there is no native way to do this.

Windows Scaling (Settings, System) to judiciously pick a scale that works for you and all the icons on your screen.

Then choose text size (Ease of Access) to enlarge text (including icons)

For example: on my 1920x1080 screen, I choose 125% scale and 110% text increase